# Как разместить html-файл на сайте, чтобы можно было его запустить и посмотреть результат его работы?

Tags: python

Сформировал с помощью folium карту и сохранил ее в виде файла `map.html`.
Как внедрить этот файл на сайт, чтобы посетителям сайта можно было запустить этот файл и рассматривать карту?

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe src=/map.html width=100% frameborder=0  />
```